# drupal imce file uploading issue

Tags: file, drupal, upload, issue-tracking, imce-file-browser

I am new to Drupal and need help with an issue involving file upload via imce. 
Everything used to work, but last week, I cannot upload files via imce to two folders in my production environment.
The permissions for the directories in question appear to be fine:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 1 apache www    12288 Jun 30 08:38 folder1
drwxrwxr-x. 1 apache www        0 Jun 30 08:13 folder2
drwxrwxr-x. 1 apache www 131072 Jun 30 09:37 tmp
```

Even tmp folder permissions look like they should allow file uploads.

I have observed the same permissions in my dev environment. The dev environment works fine - I am able to upload files without error.
In the error log it says the following: 
"The specified file `/mnt/www/mywebsite.com/tmp/1amgt3m2n7akendhdsfndgh.tmp` could not be copied to public://documents/forlder/mypdf.pdf" 
This seems to indicate a temporary folder permission issue but upon double checking it looks fine
In the imce dialog window it reports "upload failed"
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using? Have you compared the settings for the two environments for Configuration > Media > File System? (Is the production system trying to place the file where you think it is?)

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am using drupal 7 and i have checked both its exactly same

Comment: Non-programming Drupal questions are sometimes better handled on Drupal Answers (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/). That said, are the two folders the only two IMCE has trouble with or is it others as well?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is the Drupal Status page yoursite.com/admin/reports/status Look if there is an error related to the File System. If there is no error there, I would probably concur that it is not a permissions issue.

If there is something wrong it will ask you to check File system page for more info yoursite.com/admin/config/media/file-system

I don't know your set up, but for most of my sites 'Public file system path' should be sites/default/files . The 'Temporary directory' should be set to /tmp

If the Status page says you have not problems and your paths are all correct.  The next thing I would check is if you have enough free space on your server for the file you are uploading.  I have got that same error in the past when my server had less than 500GB of free space.

There are other possible answers to the question, but these are the most common problems (if your perms are correct as you indicated).

Comment: all looks fine, but when i tried to upload file it gave me an error on imce window "specified file could not be copied becuase no file by that name exists. Please check that you supplied the correct filename" but when i see the error logs i can see two error 1. ysite.com/tmp/p1anim53ni16d41o401ook1grove74.tmp could not be copied because it does not exist.2. mysite.com//tmp/p1anim53ni16d41o401ook1grove74.tmp): failed to open stream: Input/output error in plupload_handle_uploads() (line 406 of var/www/mysite.com/releases/20160712142249/htdocs/sites/all/modules/plupload/plupload.module).